# Action which affects both model data and UI

Tags: ember.js

User clicks a link. I want to do two things:

1. Update model data.
2. Show a notification that the model has been changed.

So I can have an action on the link which calls a function on the controller. From there I can easily update the model data. How should the UI get updated? And how can I have the notification presented only once the data has successfully saved on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example taken from [Yehuda's comment](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1692#issuecomment-11964398), this could cover a couple of cases depending on exactly what sort of UI update you want to perform.

```
App.NewUserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.User.createRecord();
  },

  events: {
    save: function(user) {
      user.one('didCreate', function() {
        this.transitionTo('showUser', user);
      }, this);

      this.get('store').commit();
    }
  }
});
```

Since the state of your view should mostly depend on the router/controllers as much as possible, try to keep it driven from those places. If you need some other, truly view-only UI updates, send actions to the view and send the data-related events from there to the router/controller. You should be able set up callbacks etc from here just fine.